# Java Web Application not sending email through Gmail when deployed to Amazon cloud

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have developed a Java web application, one of the required features is sending emails. The emails are sent using my own Google mail account, and this works locally.

However, when I deploy my application on-line to Amazon, most of the application is working fine but it does not send the emails.

Has anyone faced that problem before?

Comment: What stacktrace do you get? Are you sure the ports you use for mailing are not being blocked?

Comment: I'd adjusted the title to clarify what the problem is, but I think you'll probably need to provide more information.

Answer (score 1):

Even without knowing the specific problem, the answer is that **gmail is not designed for machine sending (or receiving)**. You'll hit [relatively small capacity limits](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en) and be given a 24-hour vacation. The easiest limit to hit is by sending/receiving attachments.

[Sending email via AWS SES](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-api.html) works much better.